# Electron phonon interaction : why $V(\overrightarrow{q}, \delta \epsilon)=0$ if $E-E_F>h \omega_D$ (superconductivity)

Tags: superconductivity

In my superconductivity course, we talked about the electron phonon interaction.

We said that this interaction is $0$ if $|E-E_F| > h \omega_D $

I would like to understand why ?

Why an electron at $E=E_F-h \omega_D$ doesn't feel the electron-phonon interaction for example ?

Same question for $E=E_F+h \omega_D$.

Answer (score 0):

You can justify this by using the Debye model of phonons which states that beyond a given frequency $\omega_D$, the density of states of phonons is zero.